# Why can geometric figures, such as a straight line move?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, philosophy

A Cartesian plane is just a set of points. Among those points are some that constitute a straight line. Let $L$ denote such a set of points that constitute a line and $A$, $B$ denote two distinct points on that line. Then, $AB$ denotes a segment of the line. Now, we have heard this expression "let $AB$ rotate about its one endpoint, say $A$" many times. Saying that, we would then go on to draw another line segment $AB_1$. And we would say, the line segment $AB$ has rotated from its initial position ($L$) to its final position $L_1$, the line that has both the points $A$ and $B_1$.

My question is, how can a line, a set of points, move on a plane? To understand that better, let us consider a single point first. If a point that constitute a plane moves on that plane, what does that *really* mean? If it moves from its initial position, then it's no longer there. But if it's not in its position, then it must be located on someone else's position, assuming there exists a point at *any* location on a plane. It then follows to say, there are more then two points that can exist at a certain location on a plane.

What exactly are points? If it moves from its initial position, is there a point at that position any more?

Comment: Take a simpler example.  Let $f:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ be such that $f(x) = 2x + 3.$  Then, $f$ is **mapping** each element in its domain to a specific point in its range.  The *rotation* function that you are referring to is simply a similar (but somewhat different) mapping.

Comment: We can avoid moving and "copy-paste" them; see [Euclid, Bk.I,Prop.2](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookI/propI2.html) (please, note that Euclid del with this issue exactly at the beginning of his treatise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that a point (or other figure) by itself cannot move - this is an abuse of language. Instead of

> Let $Z$ be the point $X$ rotated around $Y$ by angle $\alpha$

a more precise formulation would be

> Let $Z$ be the point that is uniquely determined by the conditions $|YX|=|YZ|$ and $\angle XYZ=\alpha$

and similarly for figures instead of a point $X$, or with reflections, translations, or whatnot instead of rotations. $Z$ is not an *actually* moved version of $X$, but rather the result of a mapping applied to $X$. As "wrong" as it is, the first formulation is really way more intuitive.

The same problem arises outside of geometry when we say, for example "pick a number and double it".